# How can I make R plot locally in a remote ssh connection?

Tags: r, ubuntu, ssh

I'm currently connection via ssh to a remote computer where I have R set up in VIM. I'm using ubuntu on both sides.

When I try to plot something from R it will appear on the remote machine rather than the local. Is there any way I can make R plot locally instead?

Comment: Do you have X Forwarding configured properly? i.e. can you view any graphical programs running on the remote machine? Try using `ssh -X` when connecting.

Comment: Thanks - that solved the issue! I was obviously not aware of this feature.

Comment: Glad it helped! I wrote it out as an answer, as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use SSH with the `-X` switch to forward graphical parameters to your local machine.

Comment: Alternatively use `-Y`, see http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1 for more info.

Comment: > plot(chaidUS)
KiTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  :
  unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''

I've set X forwarding, but not DISPLAY variable.. when it's not set, where it tires to connect to?

Comment: any way to do this without relying on X11 device?