# R Plot locally in remote SSH connection

Tags: r, plot, ssh, x-forwarded-for

I configured SSH with the -X switch as instructed in [How can I make R plot locally in a remote ssh connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317184/how-can-i-make-r-plot-locally-in-a-remote-ssh-connection). But I cannot see any plots yet. But when I use the command `xeyes &` it displays the eyes as expected.

I tried the following after executing R program.

```
library(MASS)
school = painters$School
school.fre = table(school)
cbind(school.fre)
barplot(school.fre)
```

and  also in command line using the command `R CMD BATCH barplot.r` after saving the above codes in  a file named barplot.r

What am I doing wrong? Please kindly guide me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly:

- using `xeyes` or `xterm` as a test is good: you now know x11 (and forwarding) works
- ensure R itself has x11 support and look at `capabilities()[["X11"]]` which should be `TRUE`
- patience: R plots are bitmaps, this is not always fast.  Maybe start with
  `plot(1:10)` for the simplest point plot.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. capabilities()[["X11"]] returned FALSE for R/3.2.2  So I checked in R/3.0.1, it returned true and I could see the plot. Also can you please help me to enable capabilities of R.3.2.2 please?

Comment: It depends entirely on how R was built. I look after the binary for Debian (and hence also for Ubuntu and derivatives) and can guarantee you that the prebuilt one will work. Locally built one _may_ lack the feature _if_ x11 headers were not found during the configuration step.  Talk to you sysadmin/colleagues/...